Magento 2 | Smile Elasticsuite search results get all - "*"
In Magento 2 when I search for "*" in search field, all products are shown. I noticed that this is because of Smile Elasticsuite extension. Without that it wont work.
Does anyone knows how Smile Elasticsuite handles that so that I can implement it in my store without using that extension?
Thank you in advance!
